# Unable to insert data from Spark to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

When I try to insert a record using this code

```
val myRdd = sc.cassandraTable("mykeypace", "mytable")
val myTransformedRdd = myRdd.map {
  ( myRdd.getString("field1"), myRdd.GetString("field3") )
}
myTransformedRdd.saveToCassandra("mykeyspace", "someothertable", 
SomeColumns("field1", field3"))
```

I encounter the following error:

```
value GetString is not a member of com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow]
```

What can this be?

Answer (score 0):

You've a typo. Instead of **GetString()**, it needs to be **getString()**

Comment: I have also try to getString() but it give me same error